# Laravel 4 getting information from database for drop-down form

Tags: php, database, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to make a simple authentication application and I have the login/signup form in place and it is working correctly. However, I am having issues with populating the drop-down field for a zip-code from another table. I am not really sure how i should approach this. Most of the time i would just use straight mysql query but I am assuming there is an easier way.

**Controller: (would love for the zip_code table to go here.)**

```
        public function getSignUp() {
            $userdata = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
            );
            $user = new User($userdata);
            $user->save();

            return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('signup', 'LoginController@getSignUp');
```

signup.blade.php

```
            {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}<br />
        {{ Form::text('email') }}<br />
        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}<br />
        {{ Form::password('password') }}<br />
        {{ Form::label('zip_code', 'Zip Code:') }}<br />
        {{ Form::select('zip_code', array('zip_code' => '', 'city' => '')); }}<br />     
        {{ Form::submit() }}<br />
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**This is how I would normally call database information before this**

```
        public function showHome()
{
            $testimonials = DB::select('SELECT * FROM `testimonials` WHERE `id`=' . mt_rand(1, 2));
            return View::make('home.index', array('pageTitle' => 'Home'))->with('testimonials', $testimonials);
}
```

but with me not returning a view and therefor no variables are going to be passed I am not sure how to achieve this

Any advice would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Aren't you going to display the zip codes on every request to `/dashboard`? If so, why not just grab it on it's own controller? If not, why?

Answer (score 7):

You can easily list out data from an Eloquent model for a select field using the `lists()` function.

```
Testimonial::lists('content', 'id');
```

Comment: For those curious why the `id` field is listed second, it's because the second parameter in the `lists()` method is used to specify a custom key column. More info [here](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects).